# Batch File To Remove Starting Videos in Conan Exiles DefaultGame.ini

Tags: batch-file, ini

```
@echo OFF
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FileName=F:\Program Files(x86)\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Conan Exiles\ConanSandbox\Config\DefaultGame.ini"
set "TempFile=%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"
if not exist "%FileName%" goto EndBatch

del "%TempFile%" 2>nul

for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N "^" "%FileName%"') do (
    set "Line=%%A"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if not "!Line:+StartupMovies=StartupUE4!" == "!Line!" (
    echo -StartupMovies=StartupUE4
    ) else if not "!Line:+StartupMovies=StartupNvidia!" == "!Line!" (
    echo -StartupMovies=StartupNvidia
    ) else if not "!Line:+StartupMovies=CinematicIntroV2!" == "!Line!" (
        echo -StartupMovies=CinematicIntroV2
    ) else echo(!Line:*:=!
    endlocal
) >>"%TempFile%"

rem Is the temporary file not binary equal the existing INI file, then move
rem the temporary file over existing INI file and delete the temporary file
rem if that fails like on INI file currently opened by an application with
rem no shared write access. Delete the temporary file if it is binary equal
rem the existing INI file because of nothing really changed.

%SystemRoot%\System32\fc.exe /B "%TempFile%" "%FileName%" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    move /Y "%TempFile%" "%FileName%"
    if errorlevel 1 del "%TempFile%"
) else del "%TempFile%"

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

What it starts with in that ini file

```
[/Script/MoviePlayer.MoviePlayerSettings]
bWaitForMoviesToComplete=True
bMoviesAreSkippable=True
-StartupMovies=
+StartupMovies=StartupUE4
+StartupMovies=StartupNvidia
+StartupMovies=CinematicIntroV2
```

What i want it to do

```
[/Script/MoviePlayer.MoviePlayerSettings]
bWaitForMoviesToComplete=True
bMoviesAreSkippable=True
-StartupMovies=
-StartupMovies=StartupUE4
-StartupMovies=StartupNvidia
-StartupMovies=CinematicIntroV2
```

What it Really Does

```
[/Script/MoviePlayer.MoviePlayerSettings]
bWaitForMoviesToComplete=True
bMoviesAreSkippable=True
-StartupMovies=
-StartupMovies=StartupUE4
-StartupMovies=StartupUE4
-StartupMovies=StartupUE4
```

Me and My Buddy have been at this for a bit this is as close as we have gotten to getting even remotely close before this we had it repeating and replaceing the whole ini file and repeating in a loop now we are just having trouble getting the code to work right and replace all the lines like we want it
Any ideas On How i can Possibly Fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Aaaak! It would probably be easier if you got rid of the `if not ... else ...` structure. Your double-negatives are very hard to follow.
As for your problem, examine :

```
"!Line:+StartupMovies=StartupUE4!" == "!Line!"
```

This will replace any `+StartupMovies` in `line` with `StartupUE4` and compare the result to the original value of `Line`

This means that *any* line containing `+StartupMovies` will test `FALSE`. You use a `NOT` in your `if` test, so the following `echo -StartupMovies=StartupUE4` will be executed for *any* line which contains `+StartupMovies`.

Try this:

```
....
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%FileName%") do (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "Line=%%A"
    set "regurgitate=Y"
    if "!Line:+StartupMovies=!" NEQ "!Line!" (
     rem a "+StartupMovies" line
     for %%s in (StartupUE4 StartupNvidia CinematicIntroV2) do if "!Line:%%s=!" NEQ "!Line!" (
      echo -StartupMovies=%%s
      set "regurgitate="
     )
    )
    if defined regurgitate echo %%A
    endlocal
) >>"%TempFile%"

....
```

Since `filename` is quoted (as it has to be assuming its contents *may* include spaces), then the `usebackq` modifier tells batch that it is to process the file "%FileName%". The `delims=` assigns the entire line to `%%A`.

For each line, `regurgitate` is `set` to a non-empty value. Detect the required common string and if that line also includes any of the three strings, then `echo` the `-start...` line and set the value of `regurgitate` to **empty**

If `regurgitate` survives the process, then simply echo the original unprocessed line.

Now, if you simply want to change `+startup...` to `-startup...` then this is a little shorter:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%FileName%") do (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "Line=%%A"
    echo !Line:+StartupMovies=-StartupMovies!
    endlocal
) >>"%TempFile%"
```

That is, if the string is found, replace it; otherwise, regurgitate it.

Comment: Nice, but I would do the comparison like `if /I "!Line:*+StartupMovies=!"=="+StartupMovies!Line!"` in order to ensure it matches only the beginning of a line; this could even be made case-sensitive, by removing `/I`, if needed…